# Call a variable NSString from JavaScript in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview, nsstring

I would like to catch a variable `NSString` from JavaScript in a WebView. 
In this case, the variable will be the path to the application.

---

### My code

```
 - (NSString *)pathBundle {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 }

+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)selector { return NO; }
+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char*)name { return YES; }
```

Now, I try to call this in JavaScript with `alert(app.pathBundle_);` but the alert message says `undefined`.

I already managed to implement a Objective-C function to change window title via JavaScript (`- (void)changeTitle:(NSString *)Value { ... }`), but with the `NSString` the result doesn't seem to pass from Cocoa to JS.

May someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. Here is my working code:

```
- (NSString *)pathBundle:(NSString *)Value {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
}

- (NSString *)pathResources:(NSString *)Value {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
}
```

And in JavaScript, I call it like that:

```
alert(Stz.pathBundle_());
alert(Stz.pathResources_());
```